# setting plt.text() coordinates to a variable location

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a loop that goes through a large dataset to create a data summary report.  I am trying to use a text box to display some summary statistics on top of a histogram and I want the upper right corner of my text box to be at the upper right corner of my histogram.

```
plt.hist(current_var.dropna(), bins=num_bins, label=str(variables_list[i]))
plt.text(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, summary_statistics, verticalalignment='top',
        horizontalalignment='right',
        fontsize=10,
        bbox={'facecolor':'white', 'alpha':0.6})
plt.show()
```

I could set the x_coordinate variable as a max of my dataset but is there a way to know what the max of my y axis will be on each iteration so that I can set my y_coordinate variable to that?

Comment: Did you try `plt.ylim()`? After the `plt.hist()` call?

Comment: @CT Zhu -Just did.  Works like a charm.  This is why I love stackoverflow!  Thank You!

Comment: You are welcome, you can accept your own answer so that the others know that this problem has already been resolved.

Comment: Unfortunately, it says I can't accept it for another 2 days..  Should I close the question?  Otherwise, if someone else answers it I will accept their answer and close it.

Comment: Yep, sorry, forgot to mention that part, the idea is to allow better answer to come up, if any.

Answer (score 0):

This made it work (Thanks to CT Zhu):

```
plt.hist(current_var.dropna(), bins=num_bins, label=str(variables_list[i]))
ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
plt.text(xmax-1, ymax-1, summary_statistics, verticalalignment='top',
        horizontalalignment='right',
        fontsize=10,
        bbox={'facecolor':'white', 'alpha':0.6})
plt.show()
```

I figured I would leave it up just in case someone else asks this..